# Let NSOperation Wait for CoreBluetooth Write Confirmation?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I wish to queue CoreBluetooth writes using NSOperation:

```
class BtWriteOperation: Operation
{
    private let data:           Data
    private let characteristic: CBCharacteristic
    private let peripheral:     CBPeripheral
    private let completion:     (Error?) -> ()

    init(data: Data, characteristic: CBCharacteristic, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ())
    {
        self.data           = data
        self.characteristic = characteristic
        self.peripheral     = characteristic.service.peripheral
        self.completion     = completion

        super.init()
    }

    override final func main()
    {
        peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)

        ...let the operation wait...

        let error = ...
        completion(error)
    }
}
```

Another class will create these `BtWriteOperation`s and will receive the:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)
```

`CBPeripheralDelegate` call after the Bluetooth transfer is completed.

On reception of this call how do I let the  `BtWriteOperation` continue its `main()` function?

Comment: were you able to find the solution for this ?